# Separate/convert bones into their own armature

Tags: armature, bones

I have the following setup:

[image]

Unfortunately this does not work in WorldViz. Instead I need every bone to have its own armature system. This results in an cascade of armature systems.

But I would like to reuse my already perfectly placed bones. Is there a way to convert a bone into its own armature system?

For example: The bone `Bein` would become `Armature Bein` with a pose and a bone `Bein` and this bone would be the original bone.

Here is the result I wanted to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option you're looking for is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd>.

Its called separate bones. All you need to do is select the bones you want to put in their own armature and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd>.

Now you have another armature system, with any IK's still working. 
From there if you want to have the bone it was originally attached to be the parent of it, all you would have to do is select the new armature, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + select the old armature, <kbd>TAB</kbd> into pose mode and select the bones you wanted it to be parented too.

Any pose data should still be left intact.

Answer (score 0):

Select the bones needed and just press P in edit mode (i.e. Separate Bones) and press enter to apply.

You have now a new armature.