# How do I parent another object only to a specific bone?

Tags: objects, armature, bones, parent

I have hands model which I rigged, now I want the gun to be parented to the left hand, where the problem occurs as left hand is the same object with the right hand, so by parenting the gun to the bone, in the end the gun is parented to both bones, the right hand and the left hand.

In my head I have 2 Options, either:

- Find a way to *parent* the gun only to the left hand bone
- Separate the right hand from the left hand as well as the right hand bone from left hand bone, but if so then another question arises how do I separate bones from each other?

**Here are some screenshots to make it easier**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have answered your first question, the second has been answered here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/separate-convert-bones-into-their-own-armature

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can parent an object to a specific bone using a 'Child Of' constraint:

[image]

Here, the object I want to parent to an individual bone has a 'Child Of' constraint added, with the armature and bone I want it to follow selected from the 'Target' and 'Bone' search boxes.

Pressing the 'Set Inverse' button may be required to return the object to it's original position as after choosing the target object it may jump to that bone's position.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answered both questions, both work. Appreciate that !

Comment: Old thread but additional information is always nice - not enough rep to comment but this is in response to Ray's answer: Make sure you select all of your objects and do Object -> Apply -> Position, Rotation, and Scale if you're having any issues with the "set inverse" button sending your object elsewhere!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by parenting the object using "bone" option. Select the object, than select the specific bone in pose mode, press "ctrl+p" and click "Bone".

Comment: Thanks, that helped me :) The point is to select the object and bone in `Object Mode`, then switch to `Pose Mode` and select the relevant bone then press `Ctrl + P` then select `Bone`