# how do I make a loose object follow my rigged character properly?

Tags: animation, rigging

Hisomeone new to rigging and animating here. I'm trying to animate a character. I have just successfully finished rigging my character but realised that there are some further loose objects that should follow the rigged mesh. I used the weightpaint mode on some of these objects, like the jaw, to make them follow the character. This worked succesfully, but when i tried to weight paint the eyes to the head bone (see the first picture), the eyes do not follow the character and deform (see the second picture).

[image]

[image]

I figured this isn't the correct way to make the eyes follow the rigged mesh. I also tried to join the eyes to the rigged mesh, but i still faced the same problem. What is the correct way to make my eyes (or any loose object) follow a rigged character? Sorry for if i was unclear and thanks in advance!

Comment: If a mesh does not deform can parent it directly to a pose bone.  (no weight painting nor armature modifier required)  If eyes are static could (vertex) parent them directly to head mesh.  If going to animate could add eye bones (parented to head bone) and parent each eye to each bone.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36603/how-do-i-parent-another-object-only-to-a-specific-bone/36604?r=SearchResults&s=9|0.0000#36604   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects