# How to seperate meshes that are rigged to an armature

Tags: mesh, armature

I have a model I downloaded from Models-Resource which came with a static mesh (.obj) and a rigged mesh (.psk and .dae).

With the OBJ, I can split the mesh by material like usual and texture it, no problems.

However with the PSK & DAE, if I try to split the mesh, it just removes the two that should have shown up, leaving me with only one part of what would have been there with the OBJ.

The reason why I need to split the meshes instead of just applying the materials to the joined mesh is because Blender only shows the first material, resulting in a really messed up model.

Any help? I'm happy to try and provide more details if you need them.

Comment: What you can do is, separate the mesh as well as the armature, to separate armature go here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/separate-convert-bones-into-their-own-armature